# Why Phantomjs/Selenium remove duplicated attributes on single HTML element

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing, phantomjs

Its seems that Phantomjs/selenium autmatically removes duplicate attributes on HTML elements. Does this forced from HTML standard itself (any pointer?)or some implementation defacto of webkit/gecko?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's in the HTML5 *recommendation* under section [8.1.2.3 Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#attributes-0):

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

This will also happen in other "standards-conform" browsers.

Comment: I haven't found a similar sentence in the HTML4.01 specification.